# Syntax error while select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am new to coding. I am executing this query:

```
SELECT order.*, item.* 
FROM tbl_orders order 
LEFT JOIN tbl_order_items item ON order.id=item.order_id
WHERE order.id=1;
```

How far my understanding this query is correct. But this error is occurring don't know why.

**Error:**

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order.* , item.* FROM tbl_orders order LEFT JOIN tbl_order_items item on order.i' at line 1

Can any one help me.

Comment: `order` is a __reserved__ word.

Comment: @u_mulder ooops it silly. thanks

Comment: @Strawberry the OP doesn't know before if the problem like as duplicate question

Comment: What's your point @fahrudinyuniwinanto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) `order` of mysql.

You can change the alias to something else and this will solved, Something like this:

```
SELECT ord.* , item.* FROM tbl_orders ord LEFT JOIN tbl_order_items item on ord.id=item.order_id  WHERE ord.id=1;
```

For more you can see this link:http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064

Comment: yes its correct thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do another 'other' word.
I change to orders for example.

```
SELECT orders.* , item.* FROM tbl_orders orders LEFT JOIN tbl_order_items item on orders.id=item.order_id  WHERE orders.id=1;
```

Comment: thanks for you effort

Comment: Youre wellcome @HappyCoding